# Why does Django default password hashing algorithm use 216000 iterations?

Tags: django, hash

Why does Django password hashing algorithm pbkdf2_sha256 use exactly 216000 iterations? Why no 200000 or 256000? Those numbers seem to be much more natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually the number has been [increased to 260 000 iterations in django 3.2](https://github.com/django/django/commit/f2187a227f7a3c80282658e699ae9b04023724e5). As to why exactly that number, I can't tell, but you'll probably find the explanation [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993)

Comment: It is more a trade-off between time (computational effort), and keeping data secure. As machines get more powerful to "decipher" a hash, so the number of iterations needs to be increased.

Answer (score 1):

## This is since been updated to `480000`

- https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L299